# Set custom font along with text color

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have set my navigation controller titleTextAttributes to use a custom font, i have used the following code for this

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Neon80s" size:21],NSFontAttributeName, nil]];
```

I am wanting to include a colour for this? If i do it seperately to the custom font it overrates it so the colour i'm guessing needs to be included in the above method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Neon80s` is not available in iOS, as I can see. But for `Arial` with font size 21 and text colour `red`, you can use below code.

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:21],NSFontAttributeName,[UIColor redColor],NSForegroundColorAttributeName ,nil]];
```

Comment: sorry Neon was a custom font i added.  Thanks this is exactly what i was after